# python how to increment vars in regex replacements

Tags: python, regex, increment

I want to replace multiple patterns in a file with regex.
This is my (working) code so far:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', "r") as fp:
  text = fp.read()

result = re.sub(r'pattern', 'replacement', str)
result2 = re.sub(r'anotherpattern', 'anotherreplacement2', result)
...

with open('results.txt', 'w') as fp:
   fp.write(result_x)
```

This works. But it seems to be inelegant to increment the vars names manually in every new line. How can I increment them better? It must be a for loop, I think. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the previous result once you used it. You can store the new result in the same variable:

```
text = re.sub(r'pattern1', 'replacement1', text) # str() is a string constructor!
text = re.sub(r'pattern2', 'replacement2', text)
```

You can also have a list of patterns and replacements and loop through it:

```
to_replace = [('pattern1', 'replacement1'), ('pattern2', 'replacement2')]
for pattern,replacement in to_replace:
    text = re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)
```

Or in an even more Pythonic way:

```
to_replace = [('pattern1', 'replacement1'), ('pattern2', 'replacement2')]
for pr in to_replace:
    text = re.sub(*pr, string=text)
```

Comment: Solution 1 was, what I was looking for. Thats good and nice to handle. The other solutions looks more pyhtonic, but for the time being I´m satisfied with Nr. 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python too well, but I think if you want to combine the patterns,
you could do it in a single pass using a callback.

Example:

```
def repl(m):
    contents = m.group(1)
    if m.group(1) != '':
        return sr1
    if m.group(2) != '':
        return sr2
    if m.group(3) != '':
        return sr3
    return m.group(0)


print re.sub('(stuff1)|(stuff2)|(stuff3)', repl, text)
```

And, it could also be looped inside the callback.
For instance, a var holding the fixed *number* of patterns
which is looped to test the match object.
There must be a replacement array the same size (and position) of the
number of groups in the regex.

How much of a performance increase will this give you?
Doing this in a single pass, you gain *exponential* performance.

Note that it is almost an *error* to re-examine the same text over and over again. Imagine searching the library of congress one word at a time from the beginning each time.. How long would that take ?